# Convergence of the square of the mean series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of positive numbers and $b_n=\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}{n}$ for $n=1,2,\cdots$. Assume that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^2$ converges.

Then, does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n^2$ converge?

Comment: Where is this problem from? What are your own attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: It seems that the following answer is incorrect, see the comments below. I'm leaving it for posterity but will delete if commenters think that's the better thing to do.

---

First, we'll sort $\{a_n\}$ in decreasing order, so it's a decreasing sequence.

If $A = \sum a_n^2$ converges, $\sum Ca_n^2$ also converges for any constant $C$. Then consider the first few partial sums of $B = \sum b_n^2$:

$$\frac{a_1^2}{1} + \frac{(a_1+ a_2)^2}{4} + \frac{(a_1+a_2+a_3)^2}{9} + \frac{(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4)^2}{16} + \cdots$$

That can be rearranged to:

$$B = a_1^2\left(\frac11 + \frac14 + \frac19 +\frac{1}{16}+ \cdots\right) + a^2_2\left(\frac14+\frac19+\frac{1}{16}+\cdots \right) + a_3^2\left(\frac19 + \frac{1}{16} + \cdots \right) + \\
a_1a_2\left(\frac24+\frac29+\frac{2}{16}+\cdots \right) + (a_1a_3+a_2a_3)\left(\frac29+\frac{2}{16}+\cdots \right) + (a_1a_4+a_2a_4+a_3a_4)\left(\frac{2}{16}+\cdots \right)$$

Now all of the terms in parentheses converge to $\pi^2/6$ or less, so we can treat them as constants, and we can rearrange a bit again and split the sum such that $B=S+T$, with $S$ and $T$ as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
S &= C_1a_1^2 + C_2a^2_2 + C_3a_3^2 + \cdots\\
T &= 2C_2(a_1a_2)+ 2C_3(a_1a_3+a_2a_3) + 2C_4(a_1a_4+a_2a_4+a_3a_4) + \cdots \implies\\
T &< 2C_2a_1(a_2+a_3+\cdots) + 2C_3a_2(a_3+a_4+\cdots) + 2C_4a_3(a_4+\cdots)
\end{align}
$$

While $C_n$ is not a constant, it is another decreasing series; hence $S \le (\pi^2/6)A$ and converges. That leaves us to consider $T$.

We know that $A$ converges. This means the terms of $\{a_n\}$ must decrease at least as fast as one of these:

- $n^{-r}$, where $r > 0.5$
- $q^{-n}$, where $q > 1$

Let's examine the small products in $T$. If we have $a_n\sim n^{-r}$, then:

$$a_na_{n+1} \sim n^{-r}(n+1)^{-r} = (n^2+n)^{-r} < (n^{-r})^2 \\
a_na_{n+2} \sim (n^2+2n)^{-r} < ((n+1)^{-r})^2 \dots$$

Hence, the series $a_1(a_2+a_3+a_4+\cdots) < a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2+\cdots = A$, and the other similar terms in $T$ converge by the same reasoning. Therefore $T$ converges.

If instead $a_n \sim q^{-n}$, we have:
$$a_1a_2 = q^{-3} < a_i^2, a_1a_3 = q^{-4} \le a_2^2, a_1a_4 = q^{-5} < a^2_2$$

and so forth. This one is tougher; if we were to keeping moving this along, we would see that $a_1(a_2+a_3+a_4+ \cdots) < a_1^2+ 2a_2^2 + 2 a_3^2 + \cdots$. But while larger than $A$, that's still smaller than $2A$, which is good enough. Therefore the other similar terms in $T$ converge, and $T$ itself converges.

In all cases, $B=S+T$ converges, and the proposition is correct.

Comment: No, $a_n$ is not necessarily decreasing. Also, you can't say "This means the terms of $\{a_n\}$ must decrease at least as fast as one of these:
- $n^{-r}$, where $r > 0.5$
- $q^{-n}$, where $q > 1$ "

Comment: @MathFail If the series converges, it can be reordered into a decreasing series (though not necessarily strictly decreasing).  To your second point, the series mentioned can decrease arbitrarily slowly by setting $r$ or $q$ as close as desired to $0.5$ or $1$, respectively. It there some other reason that doesn't work?

Comment: You need to prove that by permuting the $a_n$ doesn't change the character of $\sum_nb_n^2$.

Comment: Also, everything after "must decrease at least as fast as one of these" is not a proof. Sequences don't need to converge as fast as geometric for the series to converge, nor as fast as powers.

Comment: Apparently my comment didn't take? I've edited to indicate the answer is incorrect. If other commenters like @user85667 think I should delete it, I will. OP, definitely unmark as accepted answer! :)